# New insertions in textarea makes the scrollbar to jump to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea with a width of 800px and a height of 500px.

If I paste a text which needs height more than 500px then the scrollbar is being created in order to scroll up and down which is fine.

But If I paste something on the top then it jumps again to the bottom of the textarea.

How can I stop this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please create a fiddle for that

Comment: I do not see this behavior here http://jsfiddle.net/xjkw904b/

Comment: I am also using the jQuery.selection and this happens when I am replacing text inside textarea.  http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/

Answer (score 4):

When the content is added the cursor is placed at the bottom of the textarea, thus it scrolls to the bottom.

To prevent this you need to place the cursor at another position. For example if you want the cursor to stay at the same position in the text while new text is inserted at the top you can get the length of the inserted text, add it to the current cursor position, then add the text and place the cursor at the sum of both.

In JavaScript you can do it like this:

1. Take the `textarea.selectionEnd` as the current cursor position
2. Add it to `text.length`
3. Insert the text
4. Set both `textarea.selectionStart` and `textarea.selectionEnd` to the sum from point 2

Here’s an example function:

```
function addText(area, text) {
    var cursorPos = area.selectionEnd;
    var textLength = text.length;
    area.value = text + area.value;
    area.selectionEnd = area.selectionStart = cursorPos + textLength;
    area.focus();
}
```

I’ve also made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yr71uxqq/) where you can first click anywhere in the textarea then type a text in the input field and then click the button. The text will get added and the textarea will be focused with the correct cursor position.